# BufferedReader readLine() blocks method in Sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I have a problem in a Master-Slave application ... whose objective is the slave ask to the master some numbers to test -> test properly -> and return those who are primes​​...

the problem is that at some point the application crashes for both the master and the slave to where the two get stuck in readline() method ... I am not able to deal ... follow the code of master and slave

sorry about my english

Slave

```
package Cliente;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import Util.AuxiliarNumero;

public class Escravo implements Runnable {
    private Thread _thread;
    private Socket _client;
    private DataOutputStream _output;

    public Escravo() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        _thread = new Thread(this);
        conectar();
    }

    private void conectar() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        _client = new Socket("localhost", 10001);
    }

    private List<AuxiliarNumero> TestarPrimo(String result) {
        String numeros = result.replace("NUMEROSTESTAR", "");
        List<AuxiliarNumero> numerosLista = new ArrayList<AuxiliarNumero>();
        String[] valores = numeros.split(";");

        for (int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {
            String[] aux = valores[i].split(",");
            AuxiliarNumero auxiliar = new AuxiliarNumero();
            auxiliar.Id = Integer.parseInt(aux[0]);
            auxiliar.IsPrimo = ChecarPrimo(auxiliar.Numero);
            numerosLista.add(auxiliar);
        }
        return numerosLista;
    }
    private int x;
    private boolean ChecarPrimo(int num) {      
        double aux;
          int y;
          if(num%2==0){x=2;return false; }
          else{
             x=(int) Math.sqrt(num);
             while(true){
                x++;
                aux=Math.sqrt(x*x-num);
                y=(int) aux;
                if(x==(num+1)/2){return true;}
                if(aux==y){x=x+y;return false; }
             }
          } 
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
        while (true) {
                _output = new DataOutputStream(_client.getOutputStream());
                _output.writeBytes("ESPERANDONUMEROS\n");
                BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(_client.getInputStream()));
                String result = inFromClient.readLine();
                if (result.contains("FIM")) {
                    System.out.println("caiu fim escravo");
                    break;
                }

                if (result.contains("NUMEROSTESTAR")) {
                    List<AuxiliarNumero> testados = TestarPrimo(result);
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    for (AuxiliarNumero s : testados) {
                        builder.append(s.Id + "," + s.IsPrimo + ";");
                    }
                    _output.writeBytes("NUMEROSDEVOLVIDOS" + builder.toString()+"\n");
                }
            }
        }

        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Master

```
package Servidor;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import Util.AuxiliarNumero;
import Util.ListaContainer;

public class Mestre implements Runnable {

    private Socket _socket;

    public Mestre(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        _socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(_socket.getOutputStream());
            while (true) {              
                BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_socket.getInputStream()));
                System.out.println("ini erro");
                String comando = inFromClient.readLine();
                System.out.println("fim erro");
                if (comando.contains("ESPERANDONUMEROS")) {
                    if (ListaContainer.Count() == 0) {
                        System.out.println("caiu fim mestre");
                        break;
                    }
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    for (AuxiliarNumero s : ListaContainer.getNumeros()) {
                        builder.append(s.Id + "," + s.Numero + ";")    ;
                    }
                    outToServer.writeBytes("NUMEROSTESTAR" + builder.toString()+"\n");
                    System.out.println("passado numeros para cliente. Numeros Testar"+ builder.toString());                 
                }
                if (comando.contains("NUMEROSDEVOLVIDOS")) {
                    System.out.println("verificando numeros devolvidos depois de testados...");
                    ListaContainer.setNumeros(comando);
                    outToServer.writeBytes("ESPERANDONUMEROS\n");
                }
            }
            outToServer.writeBytes("FIM"+"\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } finally{

        }
    }
}
```

AuxiliarNumero

```
package Util;


public class AuxiliarNumero {

    public int Id;

    public int Numero;

    public EstadoTipo Estado;

    public boolean IsPrimo;
}
```

EstadoTipo

```
package Util;

public enum EstadoTipo {
    Testado,
    Esperando,
    NaoTestado
}
```

ListaContainer

```
package Util;

public class ListaContainer {

    public static List<AuxiliarNumero> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void inicializar(int rangeMin, int rangeMax) {

        int o = 0;
        for (int i = rangeMin; i < rangeMax; i++) {
            AuxiliarNumero aux = new AuxiliarNumero();
            aux.Id = o;
            aux.Numero = i;
            aux.Estado = EstadoTipo.NaoTestado;
            aux.IsPrimo = false;
            lista.add(aux);
            o++;
        }
    }

    public static List<AuxiliarNumero> getNumeros() {
        synchronized (lista) {
            List<AuxiliarNumero> novaLista = new ArrayList<>();
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
                if (count == 50)
                    break;
                if (lista.get(i).Estado == EstadoTipo.NaoTestado) {
                    lista.get(i).Estado = EstadoTipo.Esperando;
                    novaLista.add(lista.get(i));
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return novaLista;
        }
    }

    public static int Count() {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            if (lista.get(i).Estado == EstadoTipo.NaoTestado) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void setNumeros(String comando) {
        synchronized (lista) {
            comando = comando.replace("NUMEROSDEVOLVIDOS", "");
            String[] numeros = comando.split(";");
            for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
                String[] auxili = numeros[i].split(",");
                lista.get(Integer.parseInt(auxili[0])).IsPrimo = Boolean
                        .parseBoolean(auxili[1]);
                lista.get(Integer.parseInt(auxili[0])).Estado = EstadoTipo.Testado;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Cliente

```
package Cliente;

public class Cliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{    
    List<Escravo> _clients = new ArrayList<Escravo>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            _clients.add(new Escravo());
        }

        for (Escravo clientRun : _clients) {        
                Thread t = new Thread(clientRun);
                t.start();
                t = null;   
        }
    }
}
```

Servidor

```
package Servidor;

public class Servidor {

    public static List<AuxiliarNumero> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ListaContainer.inicializar(10, 4000);

        try {
            System.out.println("Server run...");
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(10001);
            while (true) {
                Socket connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                Mestre clientConnected = new Mestre(connectionSocket);
                Thread t = new Thread(clientConnected);
                t.start();
                t = null;
                clientConnected = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am trying to reproduce the error, but there are missing some classes... could you refactor the Code or paste the classes please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside of while i put this

```
BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_socket.getInputStream()));
```

in loop... i remove and instantiate just one time, works.

Answer (score 2):

Thus is not a crash. It is called a deadlock. Both peers are waiting for the other to send them something. This is an application protocol error. I suggest you write down the sequence of things you are sending and receiving, and see where they don't marry up.

Comment: you can help me in that? i really don't understand how i can control this

Comment: You don't have to 'control' anything. You have to *analyze.*

Comment: analyze what? I put println in the code and I know that the error starts in readline (), because at some point the line is blank inside BufferedReader master and slave expect each other ... 
but it is not defined in a moment sometimes this testing everything, sometimes only 50, sometimes more ... i thing is because i put "\n" in outToServer.writeBytes but this is Necessary ...